# Consul backend for Traefik

Tags: consul, traefik

I am trying to evaluate Consul Service discovery with Traefik as load balancer + reverse proxy.
I have run Consul on my local machine and registered service1. Also, I started Traefik on my local machine.
Now, I want Traefik to listen to Consul as backend. For this, I have put following in Traefik .toml

```
[consulCatalog]
  endpoint = "localhost:8500"
  watch = true
  prefix = ""
  domain = "consul.localhost"
```

With this, I can access service1 from Traefik as follows:
http://service1.consul.localhost:9090/

My question is that what should I put as URL if Traefik is running on some other host. Instead of localhost in above url, should I put actual IP? It does not seem to work.

Comment: Also want to confirm, am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? Is this the correct way to use Consul+Traefik combo?

Comment: Aren't you just hitting the Consul DNS with that address? Are you sure it's routed through Traefik? Or maybe I am thinking of `service1.service.consul`. By the way, you might be interested in Fabio proxy/load balancer instead

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007. It worked out as localhost:9090/service1. I will also check out Fabio.